# Add hreflang to magento language switcher

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to add hreflang="ca-fr" or  "ca-en" my code is below

```
<?php if ($_lang->getId() != $this->getCurrentStoreId()): ?>
                        <li class="language-<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getCode()); ?>">
                            <a href="#" onclick="changeLang('<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>')"
                               hreflang="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getCode()); ?>"
                               id="link-<?php echo $_lang->getId() ?>"><?php echo $frontendNameAssign[$_lang->getId()]; ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

I added the 4th line to the file but this displays as "ca_us_english", is there a way to amend this?

I have also tried amending Miscellaneous Scripts with no joy, any help would be grateful.

thanks
Mel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in this case you are "right" and Magento is "wrong".
What Magento is actually presenting you as `$_lang` is not really the lang, but one of your store.

So `ca_us_english` is the code of your english candian store in your backend (you can have a look at it in the admin under System > Manage Stores)

To get the actual local set for this store you have to use this line of code :

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $_lang->getId())
```